# How to change deprecated room transaction without spoiling fuctionality

Tags: android, transactions, deprecated

So room has deprecated the beginTransaction/setTransactionSuccessful/endTransaction and allows to use runnables and callables as replacement with runInTransaction() function.

But as far as i know, i can't get a return value from runnable or callable. What is the way to fix the code and remove the direct transactions without changing the functionality?

Observable.fromCallable is used for 2 reasons: to make database calls on non UI thread and to get a value returned once it finishes.

Haven't tried any other aproaches as I'm not sure what other aproaches could be.

```
Observable.fromCallable(//Observable.fromCallable allows to return value to subscriber
                    () -> {
                        long entryId = 0;
                        db.beginTransaction();
                        if (info.isChanged())
                            entryId = db.biDao().insert(info);
                        if (info.xChanged())
                            db.xDao().insert(info.getX());
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        db.endTransaction();
                        return entryId;//after insertion our id in to a model it should be updated since it's 0 initialized by default
                    })
                    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())             
                    //because we can set model data only on main thread      
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(//either way we close db eventually
                            entryId -> {
                                if (entryId > 0)
                                    someModel.setId(entryId);
                                someModel.setDataChanged(false);
                                db.close();
                            },//done
                            throwable -> {//error
                                db.close();
                                throwable.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    );
```

I accept alternative sollution which:
1) removes deprecation
2) runs database queries in non UI thread
3) sets the query resuts in UI thread

what i've also tried was changing part of the code, but it looks dam ugly / wrong way of using "final long[]". Any alternatives?

```
Observable.fromCallable(//Observable.fromCallable allows to return value to subscriber
                    () -> {
                        final long[] entryId = {0};
                        db.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (info.isChanged())
                                    entryId[0] = db.biDao().insert(info);
                                if (info.xChanged())
                                    db.xDao().insert(info.getX());
                            }
                        });                      
                        return entryId[0];//after insertion our id in settingsModel should be updated since it's 0 initialized.
})
                    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())             
                    //because we can set model data only on main thread      
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(//either way we close db eventually
                            entryId -> {
                                if (entryId > 0)
                                    someModel.setId(entryId);
                                someModel.setDataChanged(false);
                                db.close();
                            },//done
                            throwable -> {//error
                                db.close();
                                throwable.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    );
```

Comment: Your existing code is a bit strange. Your `Callbable` is returning `entryId`, which is not affected by the transactions that you cite. And, your code is not using the transaction calls correctly. All that being said, you could try using `@Transaction`, with your function returning a suitable RxJava type.

Comment: oops, mistakes were made in the code (sorry, late night editing...). Edited the error. EntryId is actualy an id received from the room DAO call which is suppose to be returned and saved into view model.